# trigger 'click' event every 3 seconds without clicking on the next button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

I have a liquid carousel slider set up on one of my websites located over here http://www.edhubdemo.com/wp/. The slider is located under the Our Works and the Our Clients' area and currently users can scroll through the works by clicking on the next/previous buttons. Now what I want to do is that the 'click' function should be triggered itself after every 3 seconds so that the slider moves to the next 4 set of works itself. I tried using the trigger function but I guess I couldn't integrate it correctly. Here's the code inside the liquid carousel javascript file:

```
(function($){
$.fn.liquidcarousel = function(options) {

var defaults = {
    duration: 10000
};
var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

return this.each(function() {
        var divobj = $(this);

        $(divobj).css('overflow', 'hidden');

        $('> .wrapper', divobj).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $('> .wrapper', divobj).css('float', 'left');

        $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).css('float', 'left');
        $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).css('margin', '0');
        $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).css('padding', '0');
        $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).css('display', 'block');

        $('> .wrapper > ul > li', divobj).css('display', 'block');
        $('> .wrapper > ul > li', divobj).css('float', 'left');

        var visiblelis = 0;
        var totallis = $('> .wrapper > ul > li', this).length;
        var currentposition = 0;
        var additionalmargin = 0;
        var totalwidth = 0;

        $(window).resize(function(e){
            var divwidth = $(divobj).width();
            var availablewidth = divwidth;

            var heighest = 0;
            $('> .wrapper > ul > li', divobj).css("height", "auto");
            $('> .wrapper > ul > li', divobj).each(function () {
                if ( $(this).outerHeight() > heighest ) {
                    heighest = $(this).outerHeight();
                }
            });

            $(divobj).height(heighest);
            $('> .wrapper', divobj).height(heighest);
            $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).height(heighest);
            $('> .wrapper > ul > li', divobj).height(heighest);

            var liwidth = $('> .wrapper > ul > li:first', divobj).outerWidth(true);
            var originalmarginright = parseInt($('> .wrapper > ul > li', divobj).css('marginRight'));
            var originalmarginleft = parseInt($('> .wrapper > ul > li', divobj).css('marginLeft'));
            totalwidth = liwidth + additionalmargin;

            previousvisiblelis = visiblelis;
            visiblelis = Math.floor((availablewidth / liwidth));

            if (visiblelis < totallis) {
                additionalmargin = Math.floor((availablewidth - (visiblelis * liwidth))/visiblelis);
            } else {
                additionalmargin = Math.floor((availablewidth - (totallis * liwidth))/totallis);
            }
            halfadditionalmargin = Math.floor(additionalmargin/2);
            totalwidth = liwidth + additionalmargin;

            if (visiblelis > previousvisiblelis  || totallis <= visiblelis) {
                currentposition -= (visiblelis-previousvisiblelis);
                if (currentposition < 0 || totallis <= visiblelis ) {
                    currentposition = 0;
                }
            }
            $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).css('marginLeft', -(currentposition * totalwidth));

            if (visiblelis >= totallis || ((divwidth >= (totallis * liwidth)) && options.hidearrows) ) {
                if (options.hidearrows) {
                    $('> .prev', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).hide();
                    $('> .next', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).hide();

                    additionalmargin = Math.floor((divwidth - (totallis * liwidth))/totallis);
                    halfadditionalmargin = Math.floor(additionalmargin/2);
                    totalwidth = liwidth + additionalmargin;
                    $('> .wrapper > ul > li', divobj).css('marginRight', originalmarginright + halfadditionalmargin);
                    $('> .wrapper > ul > li', divobj).css('marginLeft', originalmarginleft + halfadditionalmargin);
                }
                $('> .wrapper', divobj).width(totallis * totalwidth);
                $('> ul', divobj).width(totallis * totalwidth);
                $('> .wrapper', divobj).css('marginLeft', 0);
                currentposition = 0;
            } else {
                $('.prev', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).show();
                $('.next', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).show();
                $('> .wrapper', divobj).width(visiblelis * totalwidth);
                $('> ul', divobj).width(visiblelis * totalwidth);
            }
        });

        $('.next', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).click(function(){

            if (totallis <= visiblelis) {
                currentposition = 0;
            } else if ((currentposition + (visiblelis*2)) < totallis) {
                currentposition += visiblelis;
            } else if ((currentposition + (visiblelis*2)) >= totallis -1) {
                currentposition = totallis - visiblelis;
            }
            $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).stop();
            $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).animate({'marginLeft': -(currentposition * totalwidth)}, options.duration);

        $('.prev', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).click(function(){
            if ((currentposition - visiblelis) > 0) {
                currentposition -= visiblelis;
            } else if ((currentposition - (visiblelis*2)) <= 0) {
                currentposition = 0;
            }
            $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).stop();
            $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).animate({'marginLeft': -(currentposition * totalwidth)}, options.duration);
        });

        $('.next', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).dblclick(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            clearSelection();
        });

        $('.prev', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).dblclick(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            clearSelection();
        });

        function clearSelection() {
            if (document.selection && document.selection.empty) {
                document.selection.empty();
            } else if (window.getSelection) {
                var sel = window.getSelection();
                sel.removeAllRanges();
            }
        }

        $(window).resize();
});
```

This is the part of the code which moves the slider forward when the next button is clicked:

```
$('.next', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).click(function(){

            if (totallis <= visiblelis) {
                currentposition = 0;
            } else if ((currentposition + (visiblelis*2)) < totallis) {
                currentposition += visiblelis;
            } else if ((currentposition + (visiblelis*2)) >= totallis -1) {
                currentposition = totallis - visiblelis;
            }
            $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).stop();
            $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).animate({'marginLeft': -(currentposition * totalwidth)}, options.duration);
```

And this is the part of the code which makes the slider move backwards when the previous button is clicked:

```
$('.prev', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).click(function(){
            if ((currentposition - visiblelis) > 0) {
                currentposition -= visiblelis;
            } else if ((currentposition - (visiblelis*2)) <= 0) {
                currentposition = 0;
            }
            $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).stop();
            $('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).animate({'marginLeft': -(currentposition * totalwidth)}, options.duration);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simulate a mouse click event on `.next` by using [`createEvent("MouseEvents")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MouseEvent)

```
$('.next', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).each(function (idx, elm) {
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    elm.dispatchEvent(ev);
});
```

I did [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) because a class is non-unique, you may want to only call it for the first one.

This can then be made into a function that repeats itself every `3` seconds, e.g.

```
(function (obj, waitFor) { // wrap to catch variables
    var repeatAction = function repeatAction() { // function to be given timeout (stored in variable
        obj.each(function (idx, elm) { // and named so it can reference itself; makes life easier);
            var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            elm.dispatchEvent(ev);
        });
        window.setTimeout(repeatAction, waitFor); // re-invocation of itself
    };
    window.setTimeout(repeatAction, waitFor); // initial invocation
}($('.next', $(divobj).parents(".widget")), 3000)); // passing vars
```

---

**Edit**: As requested, [**this function inserted into the code**](http://pastebin.com/jKnG43FL). I've also fixed syntax as best I could (there were some errors in OP's syntax) and "[beautified](http://jsbeautifier.org/)" it.

Comment: I tried this code but it's not working, it's breaking the slider instead. I replaced "$('.next', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).click(function(){" with "('.next', $(divobj).parents(".widget")).each(function (idx, elm) {
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    elm.dispatchEvent(ev);
}" but nothing happened, the slider broke instead.

Comment: Did you get any error messages in the console? .. other than the SyntaxError because I forgot to close the `)`. -_- @FahadHasan

Comment: Additionally; this wasn't meant to replace the current click handler. It was meant to make use of it.

Comment: yes, it's saying: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier jquery.liquidcarousel.js:110'

Comment: sorry for being naive but would it be possible for you to put the above code, which you've told me, inside the code which I've provided in my main post? I am really not a lot experienced when it comes to jquery.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but now, in the console, it's showing an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string jquery.liquidcarousel.js:123' error. I have left the code unchanged for you to see over here http://www.edhubdemo.com/wp/, the slider keeps breaking.

Comment: I don't get this error when I paste the code from the "RAW Paste Data" section into my browser. Sorry, I don't know what went wrong here. The functions I put in my answer both seem to work (set `divobj = '.wrapper';` and `$ = jQuery` to test it from console)

Answer (score 0):

- select your element in jQuery

  var next = $('.next', $(divobj).parents(".widget"));
- then call a click on it every 3 secs

  setInterval(next.click, 3000);

However the best would be to create a function for this task (sliding the carousel), and call that function from a click. Then you can call that function directly instead of simulating a click.